# Can I change my name on minecraft java edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, xbox-network

I’ve checked mojang help and still don’t know how to change my gamertag on minecraft java edition.

Comment: You've tagged with [xbox-live], are you sure you mean Java Edition and not Bedrock or Legacy Console?

Answer (score 1):

On Java Edition, you can change your name by going to [your Mojang account](https://account.mojang.com/me) and clicking the "Change" button next to your current username.

To change your XBox gamertag, go to your XBox account through Microsoft, click the Customize option, then change your gamertag.